# error while using smartStore in salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, smartstore

I'm creating an ipad application which is integrated with salesforcemobilesdk-ios . for offline capability I'm using smartStore framework. while I'm creating the soup i'm passing SFSoupIndex's array.

> (i.e indecesArray)

You can see the code below.

```
let soupIndexForAccount__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "account__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "account__c")
        let soupIndexForAddress_Line_2__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "Address_Line_2__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "Address_Line_2__c")
        let soupIndexForCity__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "City__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "City__c")
        let soupIndexForName = SFSoupIndex(path: "Name", indexType: "string", columnName: "Name")
        let soupIndexForPhone__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "Phone__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "Phone__c")
        let soupIndexForPostal_Code__c = SFSoupIndex(path: "Postal_Code__c", indexType: "string", columnName: "Postal_Code__c")
        let soupIndexForIsPersonAccount = SFSoupIndex(path: "IsPersonAccount", indexType: "string", columnName: "IsPersonAccount")
        let indecesArray:NSArray = NSArray(objects: soupIndexForAccount__c,soupIndexForAddress_Line_2__c,soupIndexForCity__c,soupIndexForName,soupIndexForPhone__c,soupIndexForPostal_Code__c,soupIndexForIsPersonAccount)
        let registeredOrNot = self.store.registerSoup("Address", withIndexSpecs: indecesArray as [AnyObject])
            print(registeredOrNot)
        exists = self.store.soupExists("Address")
        print(exists)
        let tempToCheck = self.store.allSoupNames()
        let toSee = self.store.indicesForSoup("Address")
```

`exists` has value 'true'. That means we can understand that there is `Address` soup exists. When I'm trying to retrive `allSoupNames()` I found `nil` value in `tempToCheck` .
`toSee` variable have to have the values of indexes that we insert if there was no mistake. But it is showing nil.

Please help me finding the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking like you have made a `store` declaration wrongly. Everything is perfect.

globally you need to declare a store variable

```
var store = SFSmartStore()
```

in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
store = SFSmartStore.sharedStoreWithName(kDefaultSmartStoreName) as! SFSmartStore
```

Hope it will work :)